# using ASP.Net builtin web API in MVC Project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

i am using WebAPI MVC.Net project which has built in Web API codes.
For registration, it has function in Accounts Controller

```
// POST api/Account/Register
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("Register")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        IdentityUser user = new IdentityUser
        {
            UserName = model.UserName
        };

        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        IHttpActionResult errorResult = GetErrorResult(result);

        if (errorResult != null)
        {
            return errorResult;
        }

        return Ok();
    }
```

my API link for registration is epolleasy.azurewebsites.net/api/Account/Register which is giving error. I am unable to find the reason for this error.

Comment: unless you tell us exactly what the error is, it's unlikely we'll be able to find the reason either :-). Upon visiting the URL you gave, it says that requests via a GET method are not allowed. Is that the same error you're getting? Or are you visiting it with a POST (or other method) and getting something different?

Comment: Registering is a post command. Even when i am passing parameters it is giving the same error as you said.

Comment: if you're really making a request using POST then you **can't** be getting an error saying that GET is not allowed. Are you sending your parameters via GET or POST? N.B. if you didn't realise, using it in the browser address bar automatically generates a GET request. Use a tool like PostMan or SOAPUI to generate a POST request without a UI. BTW there's no attribute on your method to require the use of POST - is this specified somewhere else in your config, or is your code sample incomplete?

Comment: also tried using POSTMAN

Comment: tried what **exactly**? And with what result? You haven't answered either of the questions in my last comment. If you don't want take the time to provide accurate, detailed information then no-one can help you.

Comment: http://localhost:52440/api/Account/Register

This is my registration api that i want to consume.
I am passing th following using postman.

[http://epolleasy.azurewebsites.net/api/Account/Register?Email=uzairnadeem@live.com&Password=Windows@97&ConfirmPassword=Windows@97](http://epolleasy.azurewebsites.net/api/Account/Register?Email=uzairnadeem@live.com&Password=Windows@97&ConfirmPassword=Windows@97)

And I am getting this error.
The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.

Comment: ok. So, when using postman, are you sending the request as a GET or POST? Because that URL looks like it's probably formed using a GET. If you don't understand the difference, you need to look it up online and learn. Your error is telling you that the code (or application environment) is configured in such a way that you can't use a GET request. The most likely alternative that it accepts is POST. But there are others: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods